# Why is not possible to destruct an object and then instantiate it again with the same name

Tags: c++, destructor

I am creating Unit Test for code that it was written by other person, and they can not be modified.

I am trying to destroy one object, and then instantiate it from the beginning (so the constructor put it in the initial condition)

This is my code:

```
state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off; 

//Check that OFF is initial state

EXPECT_EQ(States::OFF,state_machine_test_off.get_state());

//Change and check the behaviour from OFF to the other States

state_machine_test_off.change_state(States::LOADED);
EXPECT_EQ(States::LOADED,state_machine_test_off.get_state());
state_machine_test_off.~State_Machine(); //Destructor to iniciate again the process

state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off;
state_machine_test_off.change_state(States::INITIALISED);
EXPECT_NE(States::INITIALISED,state_machine_test_off.get_state());
state_machine_test_off.~State_Machine(); //Destructor to iniciate again the process
```

And then continue. The reason that i dont want to instantiate a new object is because I have a big matrix of states, and each of them can move through change_state() to some but not to others.

I have looked in internet about Destructors, and i read that they can be call explicitly, even if it is not a very good practice.

**Maybe somebody could give me light about why this the compiler fails when I destruct and then instanciate again the object?**

PD: The destructor is a default destructor

```
state::State_Machine::~State_Machine() {}
```

Comment: Why not just set it to a default value like `Foo test = some_value; // do stuff; test = Foo{}; // "reset"`

Comment: You said  -- *and i read that they can be call explicitly, even if it is not a very good practice* -- Then you said. *the compiler fails when I destruct and then instanciate again the object?*  -- You were warned it was not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just declare another variable with the same name at the same level of scope, eve after after calling a destructor.  The destructor *does not* remove the old name from scope.

To solve your problem, I'd suggest just adding new levels of scope since it seems like you're only using your `state::State_Machine` for a few lines at any given time.

```
{ state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off;
  state_machine_test_off.change_state(States::LOADED);
  EXPECT_EQ(States::LOADED,state_machine_test_off.get_state()); }

{  state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off;
   state_machine_test_off.change_state(States::INITIALISED);
   EXPECT_NE(States::INITIALISED,state_machine_test_off.get_state()); }
```

If you still want to explicitly invoke the destructor, you have to make sure it's safe for the destructor to be called multiple times on the same object (you said you cannot modify the existing code, so either this will work or it won't).  In practice, I'd be surprised if this works well since most destructors assume the object is going to be destroyed, and won't take the time to mark it as destroyed (this may require extra state, and would definitely take require cycles).

If you are still determined, despite the complexity and risks, you could write something like this:

```
state_machine_test_off.~State_Machine(); //Destructor to iniciate again the process

new (&state_machine_test_off) state::State_Machine;
```

This leverages placement `new`, something that's completely unnecessary if you just use scope properly (see above).  You also have to consider what happens if the constructor fails, especially since you'll *still* need to handle the already desructed object having it's destructor called again.

Comment: Thank you very much, using the levels of scope it's work perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are redefining a variable you've already defined.  When you do

```
state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off;
```

You basically lock the name `state_machine_test_off` in the scope to be that variable.  You can't later on do `state::State_Machine state_machine_test_off;` to reset it because that tries to define a new variable and the name `state_machine_test_off` has already been taken.

To reconstruct the object after you destroy it, you need to use [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to have it call the constructor on that object again.  That would look like

```
new (&state_machine_test_off) state::State_Machine();
```

And now there is a new default constructed `state::State_Machine` in the storage of `state_machine_test_off`.

---

That said all of these manual calls and chances of undefined behavior go away if you just reassign the object to a default constructed value like

```
state_machine_test_off = state::State_Machine{};
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Nathan, finally used the scopes as Stephen suggest above. it seems to be easier way for me as a beginner, I don't control very much dynamic allocations right now.

Comment: @AlejandroMartinez Do note that placement new is not a dynamic allocation.  You actually aren't getting any memory.  What you are doing is using memory you already have toput a *new* object in it's place.

Comment: Oh, it is a new way to use "new" and I didn't know about it but seems to be potentially very useful. Thank you for the note